# How to style a label in QT using code

Tags: c++, qt

Seems like the most basic things trip me up.

I am trying to set the background color of a label in QT. I know I can do this using style sheets by right clicking it and adding: `background-color: blue;` or something. And that works great.

But how can I do this without the GUI view.

I know I can add

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue }");
}
```

in the mainwindow.cpp to change the main window background color, but how can I target a label with object name TestLabel, and where to place the code?

I tried

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("QLabel:TestLabel { background-color: blue }");
}
```

But that messes up my program. It compiles, but does not do as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ID selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) syntax:

```
setStyleSheet("QLabel#TestLabel { background-color: blue }");
```

This will target the specific `QLabel` whose object name is `TestLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setStyleSheet() for label too:

```
ui->TestLabel->setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");
```